# Page Being Requested Twice

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

I'm having a trouble with my CodeIgniter site. I notice everytime I go to a page, the page is requested twice by the browser (Tried on Firefox and Chrome and different computers too). Here's a screenshot from Firebug:[image]

As you can see in the image, the page `invite` is requested twice. I've looked at Chrome developer tools and it says that the second request is initiated from line 4 of the file `jquery-1.7.1.min.js`. Also, in Chrome developer tools, the second request has the same size as the first one. Yet, the response is actually empty (Same thing with Firebug). A simple Hello World PHP page still works fine though.

What could've been the cause of this problem?

Comment: If you use ajax in a webpage jquery needs to initialize the page a second time to 'find' all the new elements. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a resource requested during page load which erroneously has an almost-empty URL.  For example, in your CSS you may have `background-image: url(#)`, or an ajax call to `"#"`.  Notice that the second URL is `invite#`, not `invite`.  That's a clue.